# responsive Navbar issue, with the toggle menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive, styled-components

I have been working on a responsive website design with React and react styled components, and I have an issue with the navigation bar responsiveness, it works well for the desktop and tablet and when I made a UseState hook that shows a toggle menu instead of a navigation bar for the mobile view everything still works good, but when implementing the Hook in the code, it Shows a white screen with no details on desktop, tablet and mobile view, even that I have set the toggle menu display to none if the width is more that 375px.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { MenuIcon, CloseIcon } from "../assets/shared";
import { StyledNavLink } from "./StyledNavLink";
import { StyledNav } from "./StyledNav";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavbarLinksList = () => (
  <>
    <StyledNavLink to="/home">
      <p>00 HOME</p>
    </StyledNavLink>
    <StyledNavLink to="/destination-a">
      <p>01 DESTINATION</p>
    </StyledNavLink>
    <StyledNavLink to="/crew-a">
      <p>02 CREW</p>
    </StyledNavLink>
    <StyledNavLink to="/technology-a">
      <p>03 TECHNOLOGY</p>
    </StyledNavLink>
  </>
);

const NavBar = () => {
  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledNav>
        <div className="logo">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
              <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24" fill="#FFF" />
              <path
                fill="#0B0D17"
                d="M24 0c0 16-8 24-24 24 15.718.114 23.718 8.114 24 24 0-16 8-24 24-24-16 0-24-8-24-24z"
              />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div className="line"></div>

        <div className="nav-links-container">
          <StyledNavLink to="/home">
            <p>00 HOME</p>
          </StyledNavLink>
          <StyledNavLink to="/destination-a">
            <p>01 DESTINATION</p>
          </StyledNavLink>
          <StyledNavLink to="/crew-a">
            <p>02 CREW</p>
          </StyledNavLink>
          <StyledNavLink to="/technology-a">
            <p>03 TECHNOLOGY</p>
          </StyledNavLink>
        </div>

        <div className="toggle_menu">
          {toggleMenu ? (
            <CloseIcon onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} />
          ) : (
            <MenuIcon onClick={() => setToggleMenu(true)} />
          )}
          {toggleMenu && (
            <div className="menu_links">
              
              <NavLink to="/" className="link">
                Home
              </NavLink>
              <NavbarLinksList />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </StyledNav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

```
import styled from "styled-components";


export const StyledNav = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;

position: fixed;
width: 1672px;
height: 96px;
left: 55px;
top: 40px;

.nav-links-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;

width: 830px;
height: 96px;
left: 842px;


background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
backdrop-filter: blur(40.7742px);
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
width: 473px;
height: 1px;
left: 23.5%;
top: 50%;

background: #FFFFFF;
mix-blend-mode: normal;
opacity: 0.25;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 1.2%;
}

.toggle_menu {
    display: none;
}


.active {text-decoration: solid underline rgba(255,255,255, 1) 5px;
  text-underline-offset: 2.3em;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

width: 710px;
top: 0;
  
.nav-links-container {
    width: 470px;
    
    p {
    
height: 17px;
left: 19.94%;
right: 56.18%;
top: calc(50% - 17px/2 + 0.5px);


font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 17px;
/* identical to box height */

letter-spacing: 2.3625px;
    }
}

.line { display: none;}

.logo {margin-top: 2.5%;}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px){
    
    .toggle_menu { display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;}

}
```

Comment: Can you share a working codesandbox for this.

Comment: it feels like you may have a syntax error somewhere in your code. Are you using a linter?

Comment: @mjwils I don't actually use linter, but I just installed it and will look for the error if there is.

Comment: @Ankit I tried to make a working code sandbox, but it did't work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false);
```

should be...

```
const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = React.useState(false);
```

Worked for me.